# Can't see custom topology on DLUX

Tags: opendaylight

I created a custom topology in mininet and added flows rules to the switches. I can ping the hosts but cannot see the topology on DLUX. I tried with other topology such as single and linear, these work fine. I do not understand what is the problem with the custom topology. If someone could shed some light.

Comment: Is it just the links you cannot see, or you cannot see the nodes/switches as well? what opendaylight features have you installed?

Comment: I cannot see anything. No links,nodes or switches. I have installed l2switch and dlux. When I run the single topology it works fine, when I write a python file for the same single topology and run it as a custom topology, I cannot see the topology on the UI anymore, eventhough pingall works.

Comment: I also have mdsal-apidocs and restconf installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange that I can ping all of a sudden now without making any changes. I have faced this problem earlier too, where the controller doesn't work for a week or so and then starts running suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

try restarting ODL, like this [person is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625705/automatic-add-flow-to-ovs-switch-that-connected-to-docker-hosts). I would be suspect that
you are hitting some bug in the l2switch project. But, you can debug further
by inspecting the flows on each switch in your custom topology. Each switch
should have a flow with dl_type=0x88cc that punts to the CONTROLLER. Those
are the LLDP packets, which is how ODL will learn the links, which in turn
is how DLUX will paint them in your GUI. If the flows aren't there, then
you would want to try to figure out why? maybe the switches are ignoring
the flow programming (check switch logs), or maybe the flows are not even
being sent (you could check ODL logs, or even do a tcpdump to see if
openflow rules are being sent to the switch). If the flows are being
programmed, and the LLDP packets are being punted to ODL then the problem
could be internal to ODL and DLUX.

To be fair, DLUX is a stale project that is slated for removal. There
may be bugs you are hitting.

Comment: Thanks jamo, I will try it. I have another question which might be really dumb, but shouldn't I be able to ping between hosts without explicitly mentioning the flow rules?

Comment: yeah, l2switch should be programming flow rules to allow your hosts to ping each other.

Comment: there is no other UI for ODL is there?

Comment: no. there is no other UI, and in fact, the DLUX UI is deprecated and slated for removal in future ODL releases.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not from ODL but it's from OVS switch u need to this script for your switch controller

sudo ovs-vsctl set bridge s1 protocols=OpenFlow13

http://kspviswa.github.io/Installing-ODL-BE.html