# Can't see custom topology mininet on OpendayLight

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, mininet, openflow

I made a topology in miniedit, I saved it with the name topo2.py, when I called it in the mininet the topology didn't appear as I made it,

I have tried solutions from [Can't see custom topology on DLUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558036/cant-see-custom-topology-on-dlux) but still can't see it

```
sudo mn --custom ~/mininet/custom/topo2.py --controller=remote,ip=192.168.56.103
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem month ago, then I found my topology created on mininet on Opendaylight DLUX using the following way:

sudo mn --custom testbed.py --topo testbed --controller=remote --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13

You've to mention the protocols and topology name according to your setup.

Comment: Caught exception. Cleaning up. . .
Exception: invalid topo name topo2

Comment: i use code sudo mn --custom topo2.py --topo topo2 --controller=remote,ip=192.168.56.103 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13

Comment: It's because the name you're using for the topology is not the same as in your python script file (topo2.py) At the end of your script file it should be like following:topos = { 'yourtoponame': ( lambda: yourclassname() ) } and also the class name matters.

Comment: @Imad Any idea how to mention "protocols=OpenFlow13" when creating a mininet topology using Python Script? I was able to include "switch=OVSKernelSwitch" in the Mininet() constructor itself, but I am not able to find how to mention Protocol.